Ephesians 4: put on new man or already wearing?
I’m reading from the Wuest translation. For 4:20-24, “that you have put off” the old self. Further “that you have put on”. This means that Paul is not commanding anything. They should have already done this wardrobe switch since they were taught about Jesus in his truth.
Is the tense correct in the Weust version? The ESV translated the passage as a pointed aside. In that translation Paul writes, “assuming that you have heard about him and were taught in him, as the truth is in Jesus, to put off your old self”
The Holy Bible: English Standard Version. 2016. Wheaton, IL: Crossway Bibles.
The ESV feels like a dig while Wuest feels like a statement of fact, yet a confusing one since apparently they didn’t implement it.

I believe Paul is saying now that you know the Truth (Christ), walk in it.  Stop being your old selves and be the new man that you are in Him, as it is the least you can do (Romans 12:1).  I think it is both an admonishment and a statement...if that helps any.

The situation is a bit messier in the Greek of Eph 4:22-24 than it is possible to translate in English.  More specifically:

V22 - ἀποθέσθαι (apothesthai) = "to put off" is aorist infinitive middle voice - almost impossible to accurately translate into English, in part because (a) aorist infinitive has no tense (ie, it does not imply past present or future, its meaning must be deduced from the surrounding context), and (b) middle voice has no equivalent in English unless we say something like, "to put off oneself"
V24 - ἐνδύσασθαι (endysasthai) = "to put one" is aorist infinitive middle voice - same comments as above.

Thus, it is not surprising that different versions, some resorting to linguistic acrobatics, vary considerably from one another.  Therefore, here is my attempt to translate the force of these two verbs in context of V22-24

[You were taught] to put off your former way of life (the old man)
which is being corrupted according to its desires if deceit, and to be
renewed in the spirit of your mind, and to put on the new man
according to God, having been created in righteousness and holiness of
truth.


So it would apply to both those who had already done it and those who had to do it?

@Mary - Correct - the aorist infinitive is simply the name of a verb and does not include any tense.

I would think that looking at the context that lead to Eph. 4:20 -24 should solve the conundrum. Let's look at verse 17:

“This I say therefore, and testify in the Lord, that ye henceforth walk not as other Gentiles walk, in the vanity of their mind,” (Eph 4:17, KJV)

It is clear that Paul is asking these believers to stop doing something - that they should "...henceforth walk not as other gentiles,..."
This is the key to the change of wardrobe.
The mindset needs transforming. This is something they must do after salvation.
In KJV version, the end of verses 18 and 21 have colons, these block of verses is what seem to be in parenthesis. Verse 19 expands on verse 18 whilest verses 20 and 21 gives a contrast to verse 19.
Having done his elaborate explanation, Paul gets back to what he started with in verse 17. I can compress these verse as:
"This I say therefore...that ye henceforth walk not as other Gentiles walk...that ye put off concerning the former conversation the old man..."
This makes it obvious that 'putting off and putting on' is something every believer should do. Moreso, this is something that takes place in the mind. This act is possible because a putting off and putting on had taken place at salvation by divine circumcision. Eph.2:1,5-6; Col.2:10-13. This already took place in our spirit by circumsion not made with hands.
Hence, we are to bring into reality this divine circumcsion in our mind - this is waht we do with the help of God. Phil.2:13.
The book of Ephesian and Colossian along with Philemon were written in the same Paul's Roman imprisonment. Ephesians and Collossian complement each other. You understand each epistle in light of the other.
Hence, on he basis of Eph.4:17, I see verses 20-24 as every believer's responsibility because it has to do with the mind. It is a command from Paul. Rom.12:1-2.

Answer
Ephesians were taught to have put off the old man and to have put on the new man.
Explanation
Ephesians seem to be the newly converted Christians. Every indication in the epistle points towards that possibility.
One evidence:

“in whom we also (the earlier believers) have been chosen to an
inheritance, being predestinated according to the purpose of the One
working all things according to the counsel of His own will, for
us (the earlier believers) to be to the praise of His glory, the
ones who had previously trusted in Christ (the earlier believers);
in whom also you (the new believers in Ephesus), hearing the Word
of Truth, the gospel of your salvation, in whom also believing you
(the new believers in Ephesus) were sealed with the Holy Spirit of
promise” (Eph 1:11-13).

Another evidence:

“So, then, you are no longer strangers and tenants, but you are
fellow citizens of the saints and of the family of God” (Eph 2:19).

Faith Involves Growth
So, as the new believers, the Ephesians were “babes in Christ” (1 Cor 3:1). And as babes in Christ, Paul had to give them

“milk to drink, and not food, for you were not then able, for neither
are you yet able now. For you are yet fleshly” (1 Cor 3:2-3).

The believers cannot be satisfied with a false feeling of “already achieved” in Christ. They needed to GROW

“to the unity of the faith and of the full knowledge of the Son of
God, to a full-grown man, to the measure of the stature of the
fullness of Christ, so that we may no longer be infants” (Eph
4:13-14).

As babes in Christ, the new believers needed to study

“the rudiments of the beginning of the Words of God, and you came to
be having need of milk, and not of solid food; for everyone partaking
of milk is without experience in the Word of Righteousness, for he
is an infant. But solid food is for those full grown, having
exercised the faculties through habit, for distinction of both good
and bad” (Heb 5:12-14).

A Note
It is not to be misunderstood that to be babes in Christ is wrong. Every believer begins (should begin) his journey in faith as babes in Christ.
This is why Apostle Peter says:

“as newborn babes desire the pure soul-nourishing milk, that you may
grow by it” (1 Pet 2:2).

So, Christianity involves growth to maturity; from babies to full grown men.
Babes = New Creation
When someone believes in Christ, he is reconciled to God by justification and a new person is formed within.

“So that if anyone is in Christ, he is a new creation; the old
things have passed away; behold, all things have become new!” (2 Cor
5:17).


“For in Christ Jesus neither circumcision has any strength nor
uncircumcision, but a new creation” (Gal 6:15).

But this new person (baby) is not visible to the outsiders. It grows within the believer as an inward man.

“Because of this, we do not faint, but if indeed our outward man
is being decayed, yet the inward man (baby) is being renewed day
by day” (2 Cor 4:16).


“but the hidden man of the heart, in the incorruptible adornment
of the meek and quiet spirit, which is of great value before God” (1
Pet 3:4).


“but he is a Jew that is one inwardly, and circumcision is of
heart, in spirit, not in letter; of whom the praise is not from men,
but from God” (Rom 2:29).

Just as the newly created new man is growing the old man has to give way (to be decayed).

“knowing this, that our old man was crucified with Him, that the
body of sin might be nullified, so that we no longer serve sin” (Rom
6:6).


“Do not lie to one another, having put off the old man with his
practices, and having put on the new, having been renewed in full
knowledge according to the image of the One creating him” (Col
3:9-10).


“For you (the old man) died, and your (new) life has been hidden
with Christ in God” (Col 3:3).

As I said, this new man that is growing within the old man is hidden in Christ. Outsiders cannot see it.
When will the new man be revealed?

“Whenever Christ our life is revealed (i.e., at the Second
Coming), then also you (the new man) will be revealed with Him
in glory” (Col 3:4)!

One final thing; the new man is not an anarchist. He loves God’s commandments! He won’t believe that Christ abolished the commandments.

“For I delight in the Law of God according to the inward man” (Rom
7:22).

Ephesians Needed to Grow

“that He (God) may give you, according to the riches of His glory,
by His power to become mighty in the INWARD man through His
Spirit, that through faith Christ may dwell in your hearts, having
been rooted and founded in love, that you may be given strength to
grasp, with all the saints, what is the breadth and length and depth
and height, and to know the surpassing knowledge and love of
Christ, that you may be filled to all the fullness of God” (Eph
3:16-19).

So, it should be in this background – that the Ephesians were babies in Christ who needed to grow - that the OP’s question is to be analyzed.
Paul has become conditional as to emphasize what he wanted to stress.
Yes, Paul is not commanding anything here. They were supposed to have done this at the time of hearing the Gospel, believing in Christ, justification and reconciliation etc. which are the starting point of a Christian life and growth.

“However you did not learn Christ this way, IF indeed you heard
Him and were taught in Him, as the truth is in Jesus, for you to have
put off the old man, as regards the former behavior, having been corrupted according to the deceitful lusts, and to be renewed in the
spirit of your mind, and to have put on the new man, which
according to God was created in righteousness and true holiness”
(Eph 4:20-24).

Yes, they were taught – if taught – to have put off the old man and to have put on the new inward man.
Why is Paul conditional here?
The epistle to Ephesians was one of the prison letters Paul wrote towards the end of his life (Eph 6:20).
So by that time, he had seen that the Christian life was not very easy for long in the secular world; that believers often deflected from faith (2 Tim 1:15; 2 Tim 4:10, 16; ) after their “first love” (Rev 2:4) faded.
